# Macro to list cell values from multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I need a Macro to list cell values from multiple sheets

On each Worksheet, ("A7") is the Clients Name and ("J65") is the USD Amount due or owed.
("J65") has a formula: =SUM(J35-H62), which is the result I have with my limited writing skills.

I need a quick list on a blank sheet:

Column A
Don juan

Column B
$5,200.67

I have a code that will put my sheets in order of amount("J65"), least to greatest, I need it to list in that order. ("A7") the clients name, is also the name of the worksheet if that helps. 
Thank you

Comment: This is very simple. Did you try recording a macro? Please show us what have you tried? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
Sub Create_Report()

Dim table()
Dim data_range As Range
Dim firstcell As Range
Dim lastcell As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim msg As String

    If Not Worksheets("Report") Is Nothing Then
        Worksheets("Report").Delete
    End If

ReDim table(0 To Worksheets.Count - 1, 0 To 1)

    For i = 1 To UBound(table, 1) + 1
        table(i - 1, 0) = Worksheets(i).Range("A7")
        table(i - 1, 1) = Worksheets(i).Range("J65")
    Next i

msg = "You have to delete the sheet [Report] before creating the next report"

On Error GoTo handler
Worksheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "Report"

Set firstcell = Cells(2, 1)
Set lastcell = Cells(UBound(table, 1) + 2, UBound(table, 2) + 1)
Set data_range = Range(firstcell, lastcell)

Range("A1").Value = "Name"
Range("B1").Value = "Due / owed"
data_range = table
data_range.Sort Key1:=Range("B1"), Order1:=xlAscending

Exit Sub

handler:
    MsgBox (msg)

End Sub
```